# convert R aggregative function to python

Tags: python, r, pandas, aggregate

I now am preprocessing my data in R and then importing it to python, but it would be more convenient if I could do everything in python. Would someone know how to convert the following code to python?

```
aggregate(mrna[,c(2:178)],by=list(mrna$GeneSymbol), FUN=function(x) x=max(x))
```

Thanks!

Edit:
Example of mrna

```
GeneSymbol TCGA.2J.AAB1.01A TCGA.2J.AAB4.01A TCGA.2J.AAB6.01A TCGA.2J.AAB8.01A TCGA.2J.AAB9.01A
   A1BG          81.9122          56.7551          82.5497          56.9307         105.7878
    A1CF          25.3659          53.4512           8.1871          33.8425          21.4362
 GGACT         180.4976         111.0774         163.1228         185.8143         166.7095
    A2M       19703.8049       15837.8241        8517.4444       14413.9130       24311.7792
 A2ML1          85.8537           0.0000        1815.7895          16.9213         642.0150
```

Comment: can you show what your data frame or object`mrna` looks like?

Comment: is this enough information or do you want more?

Comment: Could you provide how you want to final dataframe to look like? Do you want to find the max value in each column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R:

```
mrna = data.frame(GeneSymbol = c("A","B","C","B","A"),
                  S1 = 1:5,
                  S2 = 6:10,
                  S3 = 11:15)

aggregate(mrna[,c(2:4)],by=list(mrna$GeneSymbol), FUN=function(x) x=max(x))

Group.1 S1  S2  S3
<chr>   <int>   <int>   <int>
A   5   10  15
B   4   9   14
C   3   8   13
```

In python

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
mrna = pd.DataFrame({'GeneSymbol':["A","B","C","B","A"]})
mrna[['S1','S2','S3']] = np.arange(1,16).reshape(3,5).T

mrna.groupby('GeneSymbol').agg('max').reset_index()
  GeneSymbol  S1  S2  S3
0          A   5  10  15
1          B   4   9  14
2          C   3   8  13
```